# Como é possível não utilizar uma dependência para compilar, mas utiliza-la em tempo de execução?

Tags: maven, build, runtime

Estudando ferramentas de build como maven, vi que é possível declarar o escopo de uma dependência apenas como runtime, o que impossibilitaria a compilação de um código que utiliza ela. Como isso é possível, não compilar uma dependência mas utiliza-la em runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem dependências que não carregam todas as suas classes no `ClassLoader` devido ao custo de carregamento, e até porque podem possuir diversos módulos separados em vários JARs.

Imagine o seguinte:

1. Processo de geração de documentos

   - A biblioteca que é utilizada nesse os documentos `pdf`, `excel` e `word`, também nessa biblioteca, existem interfaces para flexibilizar a geração de outros formatos por terceiros
   - Para a geração de cada tipo de documento, existe uma série de classes, quem sabe até um outro módulo completo (outro JAR)
   - Sua aplicação não apresentará erro de compilação na falta destes JARs extras, visto que é a biblioteca de geração de documentos que utiliza elas
   - No momento da geração destes documentos, a biblioteca irá carregar as classes relacionadas que conseguem prover a geração desejada (`pdf`, `excel`, `word`...)

Para isto serve o escopo `runtime`, você sabe que um dia pode utilizar aquele módulo por alguma funcionalidade, mas não utiliza aquela dependência diretamente em seu código.